# Levene's test with a two-way anova

Tags: r, anova, levenes-test

I am trying to perform a levenetest on my two-way anova.

```
leveneTest(Score ~ Party + Group, data = Data)
```

But R just screams at me saying

```
Error in leveneTest.formula(formula(y), data = model.frame(y), ...) : 
  Model must be completely crossed formula only.
```

Comment: So you know - this question is aprogramming issue and should be posted on stackoverflow rather than cross-validated. Just a heads up for future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting an error as your model does not include an interaction term. I would try first creating a model fit using the `lm` function:

```
fit <- lm(Score ~ Party + Group, data = Data)
```

and then using the `levene.test` function in the `s20x` package as it is a little less finicky.

```
levene.test(fit)
```

In saying all that, levene tests are actually a really poor way of checking equality of variance (EoV). They are overly sensitive to deviations, while ANOVAs are actually quite robust. You are better off just looking at a plot (i.e. `plot(fit, which =1)`) and visually assessing it for EoV. If it is for an assignment that requires it, then ignore the latter advice. Also, the samething goes for normality and the shapiro-wilks test....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a fully crossed design for the formula which means that you have use * instead of + in your formula. Because + does not imply the interaction term.

Do this:

```
leveneTest(Score ~ Party * Group, data = Data)
```

And it should work.